# How to find out the first and last occurrence of a ShortCode in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to get the first and last occurrence of a my ShortCode to print the opening HTML tag for a bootstrap panel and its closing tag.

I know how to use static variable to find out the first instance of my ShortCode in the content of a page. The following code is my current situation of my code for the ShortCode of

> add_download

the example of usage of this ShortCode in my post content would be like this.

> [add_download name='The.Hollars.2016.720p' download_link='http://localhost/mp4fs/The.Hollars.2016.720p.mp4' download_title='The.Hollars.2016.720p']
>   [add_download name='The.Dinner.2017.720p.WEB-DL' download_link='http://localhost/mp4fs/httThe.Dinner.2017.720p.WEB-DL.mp4'  download_title='The.Dinner.2017.720p.WEB-DL' ]

As you can see there is two instance of this ShortCode is occurred at the content of a post. I want to show download links inside a bootstrap pannel.

At the following you will see the code for this ShortCode.

```
    <?php 
function add_download_func( $atts ) {
    $name = $atts['name'];
    $download_title = $atts['download_title'];
    $download_link = $atts['download_link'];
    static $download_link_count;
    $download_link_count++;
    // check for first instance of shortCode
    if ($download_link_count == 1){?>
        <div class="panel panel-default videos">
            <div class="panel-heading">Download Movie</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="download_title"><?php echo $download_title; ?></div>
                    <div class="download_link">
                        <a href="<?php echo $download_link; ?>" target="_blank">Direct Download Link</a>
                    </div>
    <?php
        // check to see for the last occurrence of shortcode
        if (/* $download_link_count is the last one */){
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php
}
add_shortcode( 'add_download', 'add_download_func' );
```

Thanks in advance for any help and advice.